# firebase reset password link

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to send password reset link to users email. It sends just fine but when I click the link shows

Welcome
Firebase Hosting Setup Complete
You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go build something extraordinary!

OPEN HOSTING DOCUMENTATION

Can someone help me with this? thanks in advance

Comment: what is the link? how did you generate it? give some example links please?

Comment: The link was the resetPassword&oobCode=etc

Comment: I know I was trying to add a custom domain to the firebase webhosting site. Maybe that is why I am seeing that  "Welcome Firebase Hosting Setup Complete"